# Extending WinJS Promise object

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, promise

I wanted an easy way to add pauses into some stuff that I chain together with promises.

I thought it would be nice to include a "wait" method so I could write stuff like:

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function(complete){
    whatever()
}).wait(1000).then(function(){
    whatever2();
}).wait(500).done(function(){
    alldone();
}
```

So to do this I added a wait method to the Promise class like so:

```
if (WinJS.Promise.prototype.wait == null) {
    WinJS.Promise.prototype.wait = function (milliseconds) {
        var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
            setTimeout(complete, milliseconds);
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

It seemed to be working, but I noticed that if I use a "then", the object I get back from it, while the documentation says is a WinJS.Promise, won't have a wait function.  The promises I create all DO have the wait function, but calling .then() on a promise will cause the subsequent .wait to fail, so...

```
promise.wait(300).then().done();
```

is no problem but:

```
promise.then().wait(300).done();
```

will error out saying that there is no wait method on the Promise returned from then().

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why your code doesn't work.

The first is that Microsoft has used their own approach to creating object instances, which they do through the `WinJS.Class` namespace - this means that the prototype you are altering with the addition of your `wait` function doesn't ever get applied to the `WinJS.Promise` objects you are consuming in your code.

The second problem is that you are targeting the wrong object - the `WinJS.Promise.then` method calls `WinJS.Promise.as` which returns a `CompletePromise` object - so even if you could make your `wait` function stick, it would be in the wrong place. The `CompletePromise` definition is not in the public scope, so you'd have to do a lot of hacking to be able make the change you want.

There *is* a solution, but you have to use the `WinJS.Promise.timeout` method. You can't use this inline, which means that to get the effect you want, you will need some slightly awkward code, as follows;

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
    whatever();
    complete();
}).then(function () {
    return WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000);
}).then(whatever2).then(function() {
    return WinJS.Promise.timeout(500);
}).then(alldone);
```

Answer (score 2):

This not a direct answer to your question. Adding a `wait()` method to `Promise`'s prototype should indeed work, unless `then()` returns an object that looks like a `Promise`, quacks like a `Promise`, but is not actually a `Promise`.

That said, you do not have to implement a `wait()` method in the first place, because `Promise` already exposes a [timeout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229729.aspx) method that does the same thing (and more, actually). You're looking for its single-argument form:

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function(complete) {
    whatever();
}).timeout(1000).then(function() {
    whatever2();
}).timeout(500).done(function() {
    alldone();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think you are right about the return type not really being a Promise, even though the intellisense documentation says it is.  I had looked at the timeout option, but you can't call it against an instance of Promise.  You can call WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000), but you can't use it in a chain like this: var o = new WinJS.Promise(function () { }).timeout(1000); which is what I was trying to do with my wait function.